# I want a code that will be called everytime an app is launched, activated, or reactivated

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

```
- (void)applicationWillBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSRunAlertPanel(@"Wee I am called", @"Hello", @"OK", @"Alternate Button", @"OtherButton");


    [showdesktop showDeskHideMe];
}
```

The problem with code above is it's only launched when the app is first launched.

If after that I open up other apps, and then click the apps again from the dock, the code will not be launched.

How do I do that?

How to "deactivate" an application anyway?

Note: This is about MacOs, not IOS!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the "Notifications" section here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsapplication_Class/Reference/Reference.htm ( Sorry, can't find a direct link )

There are a bunch of notifications which you can catch ranging a wide array of different events. For example, `NSApplicationDidUnhideNotification` seems interesting in your case.
You can use the `NSNotificationCenter` to pick up on these notifications.
For more information about the NSNotificationCenter check: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i

Comment: Will try both. May change selected answer.

Comment: I need sample code here. I need an actual code that will actually be loaded when application is clicked again in the dock.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following methods:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{}
```

Comment: That's for IOS. I am asking for iMac